# Java Thread Pool Size For Production

Tags: java, concurrency

Is ( Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1 )  the correct formula for deciding on optimum thread pool size for production.

Comment: No, because it depends on the type of workload.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Thilo